# UITableView not responding to didSelectRowAtIndexPath even with delegate set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

First off, I am completely new to iOS development, so I hope there is an easier way to do things.

I am using iOS 5 storyboarding to create a dynamically generated question view.  I am trying to embed a UITableViewController inside of a UIViewController so I can define different types of questions but use the same basic template.  The code works, but when I try to select a cell didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never fired.  I have checked the datasource and the delegate and they are both set to the correct controller.  My code for the embed is:

```
CGRect questionViewRect = self.QuestionContentView.bounds;
UIViewController<QuestionViewProtocol>* questionView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MultipleChoiceQuestion"];
[questionView.view setFrame:questionViewRect];
[self.QuestionContentView addSubview:questionView.view];
```

Again I am doing this because I really like the storyboard, but I want to dynamically change that table view to something else for different kinds of questions.  Thanks for any help!

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard.  I am embedding the view from the controller on the right into a subview of the controller on the left.

[image]

Comment: where is the UITableViewController? and btw, you should name your view controllers like questionViewController. Less likely to confuse with UIView objects.

Comment: Check that the `allowsSelection` property of your UITableViewController is set to `YES`.

Comment: @MadhavanRP The controller that is being instantiated is a subclass of UITableViewController.  There may be other controllers that aren't table view controllers so I'm using a generic class with a protocol.  I have tried UITableViewController and also the specific name of the class, but neither worked

Comment: @EmileCormier I checked and first `allowsSelection` is part of the UITableView not the controller, second it is set to `YES`.  This is why I am so frustrated with the problem.  It SHOULD work. :)

Comment: Just so you know.  It isn't responding to any of the delegate methods.  I tried `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`.  Neither responded.  I just don't understand.  When I check the delegate in the dataSource methods the delegate is the correct object.  Does it get changed somewhere because I am adding the tableView as a subView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it figured out.  The problem was that the controller for my subview was being instantiated in a method and assigned to a LOCAL variable.  This means that it wasn't being retained, so when the table view tried to access it later all it got was a nil pointer.  In objective-c, methods for nil pointers just return nil so the program didn't crash.  After I added a strong pointer to the main controller class and set that controller to the instantiated sub-controller it worked perfectly.